# looking better way to check not nil and active record count bigger than zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails

currently I would like to print a report with many details, what I did currently is like sample code below

```
@report = Report.first
@details = @report.details
if @details
  # I'm using this code to check not nil
  if @details.count > 0
  # if it's not nil then I check if there is a record
    # print detail table
  end
end
```

if I'm looking better way to check not nil and the record count is bigger than zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### [any?()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-any-3F)
>
> Returns true if there are any records.

```
@report = Report.includes(:details).first
@details = @report.details
if @details.any?
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of Rails you're running, you can [use the `try` method](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try) instead.

```
if @report.try(:details).try(:any?)
    # logic
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something as the following:

```
if @report.details.present?
#rest of code
end
```

Any questions ask below

Hope it helps!